# modman: Is it ok to delete .git subdirectories?

Tags: magento-1.9, modman

I see that for every extension installed via modman there is a subdirectory named .git

I am not familiar with how Git works as I have used SVN only. My question is:

Is it ok to delete these .git directories after the extension is installed or does modman need them (e.g. for version updates etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you used modman to install the extensions. If you use `modman clone` to get the extension  then behind the scenes modman actually uses git to retrieve it. After this if you want to update the extension using `modman update` then again modman will again use git to update it. If you remove the .git directory all the git configuration for the extension will be lost and modman will not be able to update the extension.

I would recommend keeping these files but all you would be losing by removing them is the ability to update the extension. Your not going to break your Magento install by removing them.

Comment: So I actually need the .git files if I want to be able to update the extensions installed by modman?

Comment: I updated my answer to answer your question

Comment: Btw, where are the .git directories your asking about? I am assuming you mean in the extension code under the .modman dir?

Comment: Yes: ./modman/Extension_Name/.git